# ELMAH noYsod attribute when emailing?

Tags: elmah

I am new to ELMAH and am configuring it to send email. I cannot find any documentation on what the **noYsod** attribute means. I have omitted it and am getting email sent successfully, but I'd just like to know what this mystery attribute does.

Extra points...unclear on the **priority** attribute as well. Prioritizes sending from ELMAH, or tags the sent email with a priority?

```
       <errorMail 
        from="elmah@example.com" 
        to="admin@example.com" 
        subject="..."
        priority="Low|Normal|High"
        async="true|false"
        smtpPort="25"
        smtpServer="smtp.example.com" 
        useSsl="true|false"
        userName="johndoe"
        password="secret" 
        noYsod="true|false" />
```

Comment: No Yellow Screen of Death: http://elmah.googlecode.com/svn-history/r566/trunk/src/Elmah/ErrorMailModule.cs

Comment: Aha, thank you! You should put that in an answer and I'll accept. BTW, I don't see any reference to the priority attribute in that code...

Comment: See MailPriority http://code.google.com/p/elmah/source/browse/src/Elmah/ErrorMailModule.cs?r=f624a9efc8d5a7c38208822d2e71ca32d3abf8cd#227

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For those who don't want to browse through source code:

**noYsod:** Indicates whether [YSOD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Screens_of_death#ASP.NET) is attached to the e-mail or not. If true, the YSOD is not attached. Default is false.

**priority:** Sets the [MailPriority](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms223213.aspx) of the email message. Default is Normal.

Comment: Alas ta.speot.is never put his comment into an answer, so thank you for closing the loop on this question.